# Hide billing fields Woocommerce for existing clients

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to hide all checkout-fields for WP Woocommerce on the checkout page for clients who are logged in (so their info is already stored from previous orders). I am using this code, but I get errors for missing fields on pressing the checkout/finalize button.

```
/*remove billing fields for logged in users*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'hide_billing_detail_checkout' );
function hide_billing_detail_checkout( $fields ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        unset($fields['billing']);
        $fields['billing'] = array();
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

I see the unset code is probably emptying everything. I would like all fields to be just hidden visually for logged in users. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I managed to get it done myself. For whoever needs it:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'include_styles' );
function include_styles() {
    if ( is_checkout() ) {
        if( is_user_logged_in() ){
       echo '
            <style>
                .woocommerce-billing-fields {
                    display: none;
                }
            </style>
       ';
    }
  }
}
```